# Assigning a variable name through a function parameter in python

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am creating multiple dataframes with a function I have written and I want to be able to assign the name of the dataframe as an argument in the function.

```
def execute_query(query, df):
    conn.cursor().execute(query)
    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

    return df

q1 = """
select foo
from bar
"""

execute_query(q1, 'market_share_df')
```

I have written the function above and when I call it, it returns a dataframe with the proper data. However, it doesn't seem like the variable name as been assigned "market_share_df". Unsure of how to do this, any ideas are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your function, the variable `df` is just being re-assigned to be the value of the pandas function, so the name is lost.

Why don't you just make a list of data frames and append the list with the new data frame and then access them by index?

Or, make a dictionary of data frames with the key values as the names you want, and then add the new frames to the dictionary as key-value pairs?  then you could get the data frame by name from the dictionary...

To do this, just pass in the dictionary as a parameter of your function.

Comment: @Mitchell.Laferla comment back if you are stuck...  Don't want to prevent any learning here!  ;)